# Framework Source Debugging only for very limited Namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I just spent 2 hours to get it working in common, an nearly read all of the answers here I guess.
As a c# novice I wanted to learn and understand better how Interfaces are implemented and used in the Framework.

The automatic source loading only seems to work with this limited set of assemblies:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/indexedpdbs.txt

But: What can I do to debug into the ArrayList method in my example which is part of `System.Collections` and not included?

Shouldn't it be part of mscorlib, which IS part of the list?

in contrast I do can debug in to the source of e.g. any Forms properties.

here is the code, may be you know this code lines from an old exam prep book:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList shoppingCart = new ArrayList();
        shoppingCart.Add(new ShoppingCartItem("Car", 5000));
        shoppingCart.Add(new ShoppingCartItem("Book", 30));
        shoppingCart.Add(new ShoppingCartItem("Phone", 80));
        shoppingCart.Add(new ShoppingCartItem("Computer", 1000));

        shoppingCart.Sort(); // this are the two lines I wanted to examine
        shoppingCart.Reverse();


    }

    public class ShoppingCartItem : IComparable
    {
        public string itemName;
        public double price;

        public ShoppingCartItem(string _itemName, double _price)
        {
            this.itemName = _itemName;
            this.price = _price;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            ShoppingCartItem otherItem = (ShoppingCartItem)obj;
            return this.price.CompareTo(otherItem.price);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is limited, you are trying to debug optimized release-build code.  That doesn't work very well, a lot of debug info disappears when the jitter optimizer scrambles the MSIL.  Just write your own interface implementation code to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

If you do intend to learn from source code, you should now start from .NET Core 5 source code, which is fully open source,

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

By saying fully, I mean that Microsoft open sources the CLR runtime, BCL, MSBuild, compilers and everything needed.

The reference source was once published for debugging. That's why Microsoft only published a limit set of files (as you never really need to debug into simple types such as ArrayList, and they just work).

Comment: can you point me to some sources how to source debug this CoreFX similar simple as the way I tried?